# AlertDialog button doesn't work and it doesn't dismiss

Tags: android, events, listener, android-alertdialog

I have this AlertDialog that should be a duel between two players. It shows an image of a duel and after three seconds, thanks to a timer, it shows a "BANG" image. When the "BANG" image appears, the player must press the "BANG" button and the fester player wins. My problem is that the listener on the button doesn't work and i can't dismiss the alertDialog. This is the code

```
package com.example.root.gbu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DuelFrame {

private Context context;
private long startTime;
private long endTime;
private boolean timeToShot=false;
private ImageView image;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;

public DuelFrame(String enemy, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Duel against " + enemy);
        image = new ImageView(context);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duel_start);
        builder.setView(image);
        builder.setNegativeButton("BANG",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        System.out.println("********************BANG PREMUTO*************************");
                        if(timeToShot) {
                            endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
                            ConnectionStream.getOut().println("TIME:" + String.valueOf(endTime - startTime));
                        }
                        else
                            ConnectionStream.getOut().println("TIME:LOSE");
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
    }

    public void start(){
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){//mostro la finestra
            @Override
            public void run(){
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(//timer per cambiare l'immagine
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                image.getLayoutParams().height = image.getHeight();
                                image.getLayoutParams().width = image.getWidth();
                                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bang);
                                startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
                                timeToShot = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 3000);
    }

    public void cancel(){
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So i need to fix the onClickListener and the cancel() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the 
`showDialog(int)`method. 
Then override the method
`onCreateDialog(int)` inside this create the dialog and set the positive and negative buttons and then it will work.

Though this way is deprecated. You should use fragments now. But still you can give it a try!
Check this link:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Finally someone that managed to answer in a good way, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this alert box. Its work for me

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingActivity.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Message");

                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        //Code
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
```